Is it bad not to standardize all features (regression)?
I'm working with a neural network with two hidden layers for a regression task. My output values for the training set vary from 0 to 2000 and for the test set from 0 to 600. My main problem is overfitting.
I standardized SOME of the input features (StandardScaler) that had much bigger values but I didn't standardize those with values in range from -6 to 10 thinking they are small enough not to cause problems.

Is this wrong? Can this increase overfitting?

I'm currently testing ReLu with negative slope (0.01) to take into account in some way the negative input (standardized or not). Is there a better approach or a better combination of standardization-activation function to achieve optimal test set predictions?


I would appreciate any explanation or idea.
Thank you so much in advance.

Not an answer to your question, but I'd be worried about the training and test sets being so different.  Were they randomly selected?

@PeterFlom They weren't randomly selected, I tried to include similar or slightly different samples, in terms of feature values, to the test set to challenge the generalizability of the model. I'm trying to predict chemical properties (let's say fusion points), that's why the test set has different output value range. From a chemical point of view the relationship between features and target property should be the same for both the training and the test set.

I'd say that train and test set should be randomly selected. Otherwise, the idea loses a lot of its value.
